# Select options in django form data?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm basically trying to use this form as a check: If option 1(value 0) is selected: render page1, if option 2(value 1) is selected: render page 2.

Within my template I have

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/subscription/"> 
     {% csrf_token %}
     <select size="1">
          <option value="0" name="plan">Plan 1</option>
          <option value="1" name="plan">Plan 2</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

view:

```
def subscription(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/additional/')
    else:
        if '0' in request.POST:
            return render_to_response('signup/payment_plan1.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('signup/payment_plan2.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Once posted... Looking within my network path, all the post returns is the csrf. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can I use select options as a check within my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `name` attribute for your `select` element if you want to POST something.

```
<select name="foo">
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>

if request.POST.get('foo') == 'bar':
   print 'Bar'
```